# Why can I only input data from the keyboard once when I call hasNext() twice in a row?

Tags: java

When my code is like below:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
     System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
```

and I input 1, the following is what's printed in the console

```
1 // input 1
true
true
```

But when I add a **System.out.println("str -> " + sc.next());** after calling the first println(), like this:

```
System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
System.out.println("str -> " + sc.next());
System.out.println(sc.hasNext());
```

I also input a 1, what's printed in the console has changed like this:

```
1 // input 1
true
str -> 1
1 //input 1
true
```

Why can I input 1 twice when I add a **System.out.println("str -> " + sc.next());** after calling the first println()?

Comment: @Aphadite kindly to read JAVA documentation which can seen in IDE and Web.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call hasNext() as many times in succession as you want, but it's still going to report on the **next** thing in the input stream.

It cannot tell you anything about the next token after the next token.

You have to read the next token first before you can ask what is after it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, My doubts have been relieved.

Answer (score 0):

From Java Documentation

java.util.Scanner

**public boolean hasNext()**

Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. **This method may block while waiting for input to scan**. The scanner does not advance past any input.

First Input has been taken form hasNext method. since has next called without any input

Second Input has been taken from next method.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but cause I'm not a English native speaker, I cannot understand 
the professional terminology in Java Documentation. Luckily, my problem has solved.

Comment: usually documentation would be old school English. but did you get my Answer?
By the way Even I am not native English.